# I have a dynamic menuItem but I can't get an object field from this menu

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I asked a question a bit earlier about the same thing, but I have an other problem.

I need help about a dynamic menu I have. I want to get the "path" of objects in my menu.

[image]

Here is my wpf, you can see I binded Value="{Binding name}"/> because I want to display the names in my menu, not the path:

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" IsMainMenu="True">
            <MenuItem Header="Menu" x:Name="myList" Click="myList_Click">
                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>

                        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding name}"/>

                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </MenuItem>
 </Menu>
```

I binded a collection with "this.myList.ItemsSource = list;", it's what displays my dynamic menu,so here's my mainwindow.cs:

```
 public MainWindow()
{

  var list = new List<History>
        {
                new History() { name = "Guy1", path = "C:/F1/}"},
                new History() { name = "Guy2", path = "C:/F2/"},
                new History() { name = "Guy3", path = "C:/F3/"},
                new History() { name = "Guy4", path = "C:/F4"},
        };

    InitializeComponent();

    this.myList.ItemsSource = list;
}

private void myList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject obj = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
    while (obj != null && obj != myList)
    {

        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(MenuItem))
        {
            MessageBox.Show((e.OriginalSource as MenuItem).Header.ToString());
            break;
        }
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
    }
}
```

And here is a simple class that I named "History":

```
namespace MediaPlayer
{
public class History
{
    // "prop" puis "tab"
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String path { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return path;
    }
}
}
```

**What I want to do is when I click on, for example, Guy1, I want my software to display a message that says "C:/F1/" because it's Guy1, for GUY2 I want "C:/F2/".**

Do you have any idea? Do you know how can I acess the path of my object by using something like this? : MessageBox.Show((e.OriginalSource as MenuItem).Header.ToString());

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" IsMainMenu="True">
                <MenuItem Header="Menu" x:Name="myList" Click="myList_Click">
                    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <EventSetter  Event="Click" Handler="MyItemClick"/>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(easy solution)**

You can use an `EventSetter` inside the `Style` for your `MenuItem`. Syntax as such:

```
<EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MyItemClick" />
```

Inside the event handler code you can find out which item was clicked:

```
public void MyItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clickedMenuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    var clickedHistoryItem = (History)clickedMenuItem.DataContext;
    //do stuff with whatever "guy" was clicked
}
```

**(more advanced option)**

Note that using the [MVVM Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple), you can create a Command object inside the history item, and handle whatever you need to handle from there. The syntax would be:

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
```

You can look into the MVVM pattern, but the learning curve is quite steep. It will definetely pay off once your program grows through.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. My Evet="Click" is not recognized or is not accessible. What should I do? For the MVVM, I must ask my collegue he's the one handling it.

Comment: @Oxy, can you update your question to show where you have put the code?

Comment: My bad, I fixed it. I put it in my Edit.